# AdMob Interstitials not showing in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

This is my code to present the interstitial in the log it keeps saying " To get test ads on this device, call: `request.testDevices = @[ Simulator ];`

```
[super viewDidLoad];

[interstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:self];

interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];

interstitial_.adUnitID = @"MY_ID";

[interstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];



GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@[GAD_SIMULATOR_ID]];

[interstitial_ loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: I know nothing about AdMob, but does this fix it: `request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObject:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID];`?

Comment: Sadly not Linuxios but thank you for replying anyway :)